# I get wrong indexPath in the didSelectRowAt when the keyboard of the UITextView is dismissed by taping on the background

Tags: ios, swift, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a tableView. The last row of which is the UITextView while the 2 cells above are clickable(Another viewController appears by tapping on them). When I begin editing the textfield a keyboard presents so the upper cells do not fit in anymore and we do not see them.
Then I decide to hide my keyboard by tapping on the background.
The problem is: when I tap on a certain point didSelectRowAt is called. This 'certain' point is any point which appears within the borders of the 2 clickable cells described above.
It seems like after dismissing the keyboard and restoring the initial UI a gesture of touching is recognized and the system thinks that the cell was selected.
Who had experienced this problem before? How can I cope with that bug? Please share your experience

Comment: Provide the explanation with the screenshots and code. Provide precise details.

Answer (score 1):

This question is not clear. You get wrong index path selected or you don’t want any selection at all?

When you show keyboard and update UI, you can disable any selection in the table. After you’re done with the keyboard, you can enable it again.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614911-allowsselection